# There's a redirect loop on some russian tags with synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Some tags <s>have</s> *had* redirect loops, for example [лексикон](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd)

Some tags do not, for example: [предлоги](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8)

Fix it!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that looks bad. Looking at it. Possibly related to tag synonyms. Investigating.

[image]

---

Update: I've deleted the offending synonyms. It is obviously incorrect that it was *possible* to get into this state, so I'll try to prevent that happening again.

Comment: Marc, apparently some synonyms had been provided and I didn't know about it, so when I did it *again* it broke some tags (the ones I did). Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @Alenanno perhaps the real problem is that *it let you*

Comment: If it helps you: The "broken" tags are both Russian. As in, both Master and Synonym are Russian. This way, you'll locate them instantly without checking one at a time. The Synonym should be in English (the other tags that are organized like that work correctly).

Comment: @Alenanno indeed - I'm just hopping into the db server to track them down in bulk

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help and the great efficiency. (I had noticed the problem and you posted this **in a matter of minutes**.) :)

Comment: @Alenanno fixed now; I entirely blame myself - the system should not have let it happen

Comment: Don't blame yourself! You did a great job! :D Thank you. :) By the way, now I can set the English synonyms for those tags, correct?

Comment: @Alenanno try it with one first - check it doesn't go crazy ;p

Comment: @Alenanno besides; it's [always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) - actually, we have a... *peculiar* attitude to blame here: even if it is important that blame is *had*, it isn't necessarily important for blame to be apportioned *accurately* - so let's just rush over that part, so we can hurry up and fix it. We actually (I'm not kidding) have a "wheel of blame", which randomly selects someone to blame, on request.

Comment: @Alenanno can you remember which UI you used to create those? I've tried to do it locally, but I just get "Proposing a synonym to itself makes no sense"

Comment: I replied to you in TL. :)